Need the Default value for "jsonBody" in "ContractTestConfig" of Portman
In Portman (tool that helps create Postman collections), What is the default boolean value of jsonBody in ContractTestConfig
The docs say that the type is boolean, but they don't specify if the default value is [true or false].
https://github.com/apideck-libraries/portman

jsonBody (Boolean) : Adds the test if the response body is matching the expected content-type defined in the OpenAPI spec.

In PortmanConfig.ts, the type for JsonBody is defined as,
type ContractTest = {
  enabled: boolean
  excludeForOperations?: string[]
}
type JsonBody = ContractTest
export type ContractTestConfig = {
  openApiOperationIds?: string[]
  openApiOperationId?: string
  openApiOperation?: string
  excludeForOperations?: string[]
  statusSuccess?: StatusSuccess
  statusCode?: StatusCode
  contentType?: ContentType
  jsonBody?: JsonBody
  schemaValidation?: SchemaValidation
  additionalProperties?: additionalProperties
  headersPresent?: HeadersPresent
  responseTime?: ResponseTime
}

